# How do I get Bootstrap file input data to controller in MVC 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the [Bootstrap File Input](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input) plugin to upload an image in my ASP.Net MVC 5 application form. I'm not sure what I need to see on the controller or what I need to do in javascript to get this to work. Currently there is an error that is being thrown when I submit my data in the form that says

> "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters."

Here is my StudentController.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(EditStudentViewModel studentViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ...other code left out
```

Here is my javascript

```
$("#input-20").fileinput({
'type': 'POST',
'cache': false,
'browseClass': 'btn btn-primary btn-block',
'showCaption': false,
'showRemove': false,
'showUpload': false,
'uploadAsync': false,
'maxFileCount': 1,
'allowedFileExtensions': ['jpg', 'png', 'gif'],
'allowedFileTypes': ['image']
'uploadUrl': '@Url.Action("Edit", "Student")'
```

});

*Are these the correct 'uploadUrl' parameters
Here is my form that submits the data to the controller. You can see I'm submitting what in the ViewModel as well as the image. The byte[] that represents the iamge is in the view model

```
@model YogaBandy.DomainClasses.ViewModels.Student.EditStudentViewModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@Html.Partial("_MenuPartial")

<div class="row submenurow">
    @Html.Partial("_StudentTeacherProfilePartial")
    <div class="col-md-9 submenucol2">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Student", new { ReturnUrl =    ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.StudentId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AspNetUserRefId)    
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Student Picture</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TestImage, new { @type = "file", @id = "input-20" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Student Profile</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CatchPhrase, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CatchPhrase, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CatchPhrase, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                ...other form-group's left out below to save space  
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Here is my ViewModel being submitted to the controller

```
public class EditStudentViewModel
{
    public byte[] TestImage { get; set; }
    ...other values left out
}
```

Comment: You form should have the attribute `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` (or does the plugin add that anyway?). And I think your property needs to be ` HttpPostedFileBase TestImage`

Comment: just 'HttpPostedFileBase TestImage' ? what about my viewmodel and all its data?

Comment: I mean the property `TestImage` should be typeof `HttpPostedFileBase` not `byte[]` if your posting back your model

Comment: this worked THANKS! one last question, if this is a profile pic and I can limit the size or manipulate the size to under varbinary(max) then should I keep them in my DB? or should I still storethem in the app_data folder?

Comment: I have seen arguments for and against. You really need to make that assessment yourself - too opinion based for SO :)

Comment: in your opinion, when would you justify using just a db vs storing profile pics on local storage?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70682/discussion-between-user1186050-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: Too many variables to give you an opinion, but suggest you look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay) for some pros and cons.